# HttpWebrequest with Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, httpwebrequest, httpwebresponse

I am trying to download a report off of our company website using VbNet. I have the following code:

```
    Dim hwrequest As Net.HttpWebRequest = Net.HttpWebRequest.Create("https://delph.am.mycompany.com/apps/Reports/ExportDocument11.asp?ID=826&Request=List&OpenType=Edit")
    hwrequest.CookieContainer = cookies
    hwrequest.Accept = "*/*"
    hwrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = False
    hwrequest.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1"
    hwrequest.Timeout = 60000
    hwrequest.Method = "GET"
    Dim hwresponse As Net.HttpWebResponse = hwrequest.GetResponse()
    If hwresponse.StatusCode = Net.HttpStatusCode.OK Then
        Dim responseStream As IO.StreamReader = _
          New IO.StreamReader(hwresponse.GetResponseStream())
        responseData = responseStream.ReadToEnd()
    End If
```

But the Response object just returns:

```
 <head><title>Object moved</title></head>
 <body><h1>Object Moved</h1>This object may be found <a HREF="/Security/ErrorTrap.asp? 
 ErrorID=7">here</a>.</body>
```

and the Location header of the response returns: {X=46,Y=46} and I am not sure what that means.

Can anyone please tell me what I am doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing  `hwrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = False` to  `hwrequest.AllowAutoRedirect = True`

```
hwrequest.UserAgent = "http_requester/0.1"
```

may also be causing you troubles.